# CKEditor 4 not loading config.js after redirect

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate CKEditor 4.20.2 into MantisBt.

It is working if I post a simple message:

[CKEditor after loading an issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uvuE.png)

It works even after I post a note, but if I attach a file and post the note, the editor will not load properly after redirecting back to the page:
[CKEditor after posting a note with an attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHOAM.png)

I can see in the request_log that it loads properly for simple messages:
[request_log after loading an issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkaTe.png)

After posting an attachment, only these files are loaded:
[request_log after posting a note with an attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb4ew.png)

My config.js is created with the custom builder:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2022, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Dialog windows are also simplified.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

The ckeditor.js is always included in the `<head></head>` and the textarea is always replaced at the bottom of body with `ckeditor_init.js`.

I've tried to remove it first if it's already there, because I noticed that somehow JS variables were kept after redirecting (bugnoteadd_form existed and thrown an error in console)

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['bugnote_text']) {
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['bugnote_text']);
}
CKEDITOR.replace("bugnote_text");
try {
    var bugnoteadd_form;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
bugnoteadd_form = document.getElementById("bugnoteadd");
bugnoteadd_form.onsubmit = function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances['bugnote_text'].updateElement();
}
```

I needed updateElement(), because the original textarea didn't update properly if I attached a file.

What can I do to make it work properly?

Edit: forgot to mention, but attachment upload is not handled through CKEditor, it uses Dropzone.js 5.5.0 bundled with MantisBt